# I cant hit my code behind method on ajax call with debugger in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, authentication, webforms

I have a web forms page that I am trying to implement Google Sign on. I am mostly doing this from javascript but trying to implement the formsauthenthentication cookies that the page already uses also to set roles and apply permissions. I am checking the hd claim to make sure whoever try's to get into the app is apart of our domain. this is my javascript.

```
 <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            let boolRedirectUrl = false;
            const id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            const pathname = window.location.pathname;
            const url = window.location.href;
            let redirectPath = "";
            if (window.location.href.indexOf("ReturnUrl") > -1) {
                boolRedirectUrl = true;
                redirectPath = readQueryString("ReturnUrl");
            }
            const googleUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" + id_token;
            $.ajax({
                url: googleUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{}',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: (data, status, xhr) => {
                    const domain = data.hd;
                    const email = data.email;
                    if (domain === "ourdomain.com") {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "GoogleSignIn.aspx/GoogleLogin",
                            type: "POST",
                            async: true,
                            data: { 'email': email },
                            success: (data, status, xhr) => {
                               // window.location = "../../Default.aspx";
                            },
                            error: (xhr, status, error) => {
                                console.log("I stopeed on the call to controller " + status);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                },
                error: (xhr, status, error) => {
                    console.log(status);
                }
            });
        };

        function readQueryString(key) {
            key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&");
            var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]" + key + "=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
            return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
    </script>
```

on the last ajax call I am trying to hit Googlelogin on Googlesignin.aspx page

I have break points on that method hoping I can step through to make sure everything is working correctly here is my code behind

```
public partial class GoogleSignIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GoogleLogin(string email)
    {

        string userID = "";
        using (var context = new KPDataContext(KP.Common.KPConnectionString))
        {

            var user = context.Employees.Where(p => p.Email == email);

            foreach (var e in user)
            {
                userID = e.Username;
            }
        }

        Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["UserName"] = userID;

        if (userID != "")
        {

            HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, userID);
            cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userID, false);
        }


    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint right on the curly after public void GoogleLogin and it doesnt get hit but when I look at the network tab in chrome it says it hits this method and recieves a 200 response but I can't tell what the code is doing or if it is setting my formsaughtentication cookies or if username is not coming back from the server because when I try to get the username it is empty on my default page.

```
  protected string CurrentUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.Page.User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
```

I have a break point here and Page.User.Identity.Name is always null and this is where if you put in your username with a password it would be passed and roles would be set. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here not sure If I can calling this method right but being able to debug it might give me an idea

[image]

I am not sure if my web.config matters in this situation I do have debugging mode on

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="720" slidingExpiration="true" />
      <!--
      <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="720" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" />
      -->
    </authentication>


    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ASPNETMembership" applicationName="KPOnline" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <membership defaultProvider="KMSMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <!--
        ********************* IMPORTANT *************************
        The application name is used to store the user information
        in membership. 

        Custom multi-application support will store basic user data
        for other apps but all the users login data will be stored 
        under KPOnline application so please DO NO CHANGE this name.
        ********************* IMPORTANT *************************
        -->

        <add name="KMSMembershipProvider" type="KMSSecurity.KMSMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="KPConnectionString"
             applicationName="KPOnline"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10"
             passwordFormat="Hashed" />

      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: When running the application, are you pressing "F5" or CTRL+F5?

Comment: @Tomerz I am and I still can't get it to hit my break point

Comment: When you go to Build->Configuration manager; under Active Solution configuration do you have Debug. If you have multiple projects or so it can be that it is set to an other project or to release.

Comment: https://github.com/kblau237/WebForms- incorporates this.  I have yet to make it easy to make database tables, but with effort you can bring this up, or just browse the code.